# c# application crashes on ShowDialog() after running oledbconnection

Tags: c#, oledb

I have been working on a c# project that connects to a access database, but a certain sequence of events causes it to crash with a `AccessViolationException`

The issue comes after calling a database connection using oledb in a separate form than the savefiledialog, and than calling `savefiledialog1.ShowDialog()`

Note: This also applies to the open file dialog.

Comment: Have you googled this problem? I get good results: http://www.google.de/search?source=ig&hl=de&rlz=&=&q=AccessViolationException+connection+dialog&btnG=Google-Suche&aq=f&oq=

Comment: Yeah, but it didn't help with my issue.

Answer (score 1):

It might be [a bug in Access Database Engine 2010](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/e3fc5f25-79e9-4cb6-814f-a25c812759f1). Use [2007](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7554f536-8c28-4598-9b72-ef94e038c891&displaylang=en) instead.

- connect.microsoft.com: [oledb-operations-cause-accessviolationexception-during-savefiledialog](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/624503/oledb-operations-cause-accessviolationexception-during-savefiledialog)
- Codeproject: [OpenFileDialog + OleDbConnection = AccessViolationException](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/106826/OpenFileDialog-plus-OleDbConnection-equals-AccessV.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are using System.Data.OleDb from System.data.dll

Then  try something like this:

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Declare Command
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(YourSQL);

        // Set the Connection to the new OleDbConnection.
        command.Connection = connection;

        // Open the connection and execute the command.
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        // The connection is automatically closed when the
        // code exits the using block.
     }
```

Comment: The error is not being thrown by the connection, it is being thrown by the ShowDialog() function.

Comment: yeah, but I want you to try use another example of the same, because there must be something external causing your ShowDialog to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, too, and this helped me:
I added "OLE DB Services=-1" in my connectionstring, now the problem is solved.

See: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/106826/OpenFileDialog-plus-OleDbConnection-equals-AccessV.aspx   SOLUTION 8